# Cygwin can't find files in shell script

Tags: shell, cygwin

I am running a shell script in Cygwin, and the files in the shell script aren't showing up, even though they are definitely in the same directory as the shell script.

Cygwin command:

```
$ bash `cygpath --unix "C:\Users\myName\Documents\projectFile\dygraphsMaster\generate-combined.sh"`
```

Shell script (from [dygraphs.com](http://dygraphs.com/)):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Generates a single JS file that's easier to include.

GetSources () {
  # This list needs to be kept in sync w/ the one in dygraph-dev.js
  # and the one in jsTestDriver.conf. Order matters, except for the plugins.
  for F in \
    dashed-canvas.js \
    dygraph-options.js \
    dygraph-layout.js \
    dygraph-canvas.js \
    dygraph.js \
    dygraph-utils.js \
    dygraph-gviz.js \
    dygraph-interaction-model.js \
    dygraph-tickers.js \
    dygraph-plugin-base.js \
    plugins/*.js \
    dygraph-plugin-install.js \
    datahandler/datahandler.js \
    datahandler/default.js \
    datahandler/default-fractions.js \
    datahandler/bars.js \
    datahandler/bars-custom.js \
    datahandler/bars-error.js \
    datahandler/bars-fractions.js 
  do
      echo "$F"
  done
}

# Pack all the JS together.
CatSources () {
  GetSources \
  | xargs cat \
  | perl -ne 'print unless m,REMOVE_FOR_COMBINED,..m,/REMOVE_FOR_COMBINED,'
}

Copyright () {
  echo '/*! @license Copyright 2014 Dan Vanderkam (danvdk@gmail.com) MIT-licensed (http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT) */'
}

CatCompressed () {
  Copyright
  CatSources \
  | grep -v '"use strict";' \
  | node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs -c warnings=false -m
}

ACTION="${1:-update}"
case "$ACTION" in
ls)
  GetSources
  ;;
cat)
  Copyright
  CatSources
  ;;
compress*|cat_compress*)
  CatCompressed
  ;;
update)
  CatCompressed > dygraph-combined.js
  chmod a+r dygraph-combined.js
  ;;
*)
  echo >&2 "Unknown action '$ACTION'"
  exit 1
  ;;
esac
```

Comment: What is the meaning of _aren't showing up_? What is your interactive shell, from which you invoke the _bash_ command? What happesn if you run it with `bash -x .....` instead?

Answer (score 1):

In which directory are you when executing this? In the same folder as the script itself?

Can you try this:

```
cd /cygdrive/c/Users/myName/Documents/projectFile/dygraphsMaster/
./generate-combined.sh
```

Comment: I tried it. First the current directory changed. When I ran `./generate-combined.sh' again, I got a list of files in the directory, and then the error "/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
           xargs: cat: terminated by signal 13"

Comment: This means that the script files can be found. Therefore this specific question is solved.

You were in the wrong directory before you executed the shell script. It searches in the current working directory, not necessarily in the directory where it is located.

Comment: @dmr Cygwin can't find node. You need to replace "/usr/bin/env node" in the shell script with the correct path to node on your system.

Answer (score 0):

You're using backslashes in a unix context - they're going to be treated as escapes.

e.g.

```
marc@host ~
$ ls c:\users
ls: cannot access c:users: No such file or directory
                    ^---look, mom! No slashes!

marc@host ~
$ ls c:\\users
adm1n    Default User         DefaultAppPool  LocalAdm1n  Public
etc...
```

So...

```
$ bash `cygpath --unix "C:\\Users\\myName\\etc...
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the shell script runs- it just doesn't find the various javascript files that it's supposed to.

Comment: Just to be sure, I tried doubling the \. Didn't help.

Comment: probably a path issue too. You'll be running this off in directory `X`, while your script is off in `/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/`-land somewhere. `cat dashed-canvas.js` won't cat anything if the file's not in the same dir as the shell script's CWD.

Comment: The javascript files contained in the script are in the same directory as the shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Often this is related to the EOL characters.

Try:

dos2unix generate-combined.sh